# Toggle div's on hover

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-hover

I have a test UL list that goes like this:

```
<ul>
<li id="firstdiv">First div</li>
<li id="seconddiv">Second div</li>
<li id="thirddiv">Third div</li>
....
</ul>
```

And, bellow that i have related div's, aka:

```
<div id="firstdiv">Content Here</div>
<div id="seconddiv">Content Here</div>
<div id="thirddiv">Content Here</div>
```

I was wondering how could i make each div only shows when its LI item is hovered, maybe with some fadein effect.
I tried with some other answers from here, but no luck :\

Comment: `id`s must be unique. That's important.

Comment: Can you show us the javascript/jquery code you've tried?

Comment: Read jQuery documentation for mouse events: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/

Comment: see my answer and test it, that is the answer what you want. with fadeIn and FadeOut

Answer (score 4):

As I've mentioned, it is important that your `id`s are unique. So you need to find another way to reference your `<div>`s. May I suggest using `data-*` attributes:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li data-id="firstdiv">First div</li>
    <li data-id="seconddiv">Second div</li>
    <li data-id="thirddiv">Third div</li>
</ul>
```

Then your jQuery could look something like the following:

```
$('ul li').on({
    'mouseenter':function(){
        $('#'+$(this).data('id')).fadeIn();
    },'mouseleave':function(){
        $('#'+$(this).data('id')).fadeOut();
    }
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/X2trY/)

Comment: Or use @Felix soultion if you dont want fade effect.

Comment: This is great, but by default they are opened/showed.
I would need only the first one to be opened.So, user hovers over some other item, and its displayed.He moves cursor away, again, first one appears

Comment: That sounds like another question ;)

Answer (score 3):

Please see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/26C7d/).

Also keep ID's unique.

Here's some code from the fiddle:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul>li').hover(function(){
        $('#d'+$(this).prop('id')).show();
    }, function() {
        $('#d'+$(this).prop('id')).hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Chang your id to class

```
<ul>
<li class="firstdiv">First div</li>
<li class="seconddiv">Second div</li>
<li class="thirddiv">Third div</li>
</ul>

<div class="firstdiv">Content 1 Here</div>
<div class="seconddiv">Content 2 Here</div>
<div class="thirddiv">Content 3 Here</div>
```

then you can use:

```
$('ul li').hover(function() {
    var cls = $(this).attr('class');
    $('div.'+cls).toggle();
})
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WjKyF/)**

Comment: What if those list items have more than one class?

Comment: Sure, but just a thought. I didn't down-vote it, did I?

Comment: use .hasClass better than checking class like that. https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

**html code**

```
<ul>
<li id="firstli">First div</li>
<li id="secondli">Second div</li>
<li id="thirdli">Third div</li>
</ul>

<div id="firstdiv">Content Here</div>
<div id="seconddiv">Content Here</div>
<div id="thirddiv">Content Here</div>
```

**javascript.**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("#firstdiv").hide();
 $("#seconddiv").hide();
 $("#thirddiv").hide();

    $("#firstli").hover(function(){
      $("#firstdiv").show();
    });
    $("#secondli").hover(function(){
      $("#seconddiv").show();
    });
    $("#thirdli").hover(function(){
      $("#thirddiv").show();
    });
});
```

**see output:** [<kbd>**fiddle demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/937mY/)

Answer (score 0):

You should give unique id's to elements

```
<ul>
<li id="firstdiv">First div</li>
<li id="seconddiv">Second div</li>
<li id="thirddiv">Third div</li>

</ul>

<div class="myclass" id="firstdiv1">Content1 Here</div>
<div class="myclass" id="seconddiv1">Content2 Here</div>
<div class="myclass" id="thirddiv1">Content3 Here</div>

$(".myclass").hide();
$("ul li").hover(function(){
$(".myclass").hide();
$("#"+this.id+1).show();
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/S38AH/5/)

Answer (score 0):

**This is your answer**

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.hidden_div{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}
</style>
<script src="script/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li").mouseover(function(){
        var id=$(this).attr('id');

        $('.hidden_div').fadeOut();
        $("."+id).fadeIn();
    })

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
<li id="firstdiv">First div</li>
<li id="seconddiv">Second div</li>
<li id="thirddiv">Third div</li>
</ul>

<div class="firstdiv hidden_div">Content 1</div>
<div class="seconddiv hidden_div">Content 2</div>
<div class="thirddiv hidden_div">Content 3</div>
</body>
</html>
```

*just change the location of your script*

Comment: Can i pick your brain with something else? :)
When tested, this works perfectly, but when i deploy it, it isnt :\